# referencing a CTE in INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Does a CTE exist in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA in SQL SERVER 2008?

I'm trying to write a query using CTEs, and I need to reference the CTE from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA like this:

```
SELECT R.RowNum, c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.firstName, c.lastName, c.userEmail,       c.assessmentTitle order by c.officeTitle asc) as RowNum
    from class as c
) as R
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS] as c on
c.TABLE_NAME = 'myCTE' and c.COLUMN_NAME not in('LastName', 'firstName',     'userEmail', 'officeTitle')
```

But I get no results.

I think that's because I can't reference a CTE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Is there a way to make this work?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cte does not exist in the information schema, it only "exists" as it's run, like a table variable.

The solution would be to reference the table that the cte references, rather than the cte itself, if it's multiple tables, create a view using the cte.

Comment: my CTE is a JOIN of 2 tables, can I do a JOIN using INFORMATION_SCHEMA? Thanks

Comment: You could create a view using those 2 tables, then access that via the information schema.